# Making a delegate for a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, delegates

I've looked all over, and found many people with similar problems, but I still can't get my delegates working. I want to make a model view controller pop up, then call a method in the view that made the model view asking it to dismiss it. So I have this line:

```
mergeConfig *view = [[mergeConfig alloc] initWithNibName:@"mergeConfig" bundle:nil];
```

and I'm trying `[view setDelegate:self];` as said to on [apple's developer pages,](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) but expectably my model view doesn't have a setDelegate method.

So what I want to know is, how do I get it so that I can set a delegate? And then once I do, does it just automatically pass calls to methods to methods in the parent view with the same name? Apple's pages didn't say what code to put in the model view controller.

Comment: @Tim Dean is right, as much as documentation misleads us to think delegates are magic, they are really just stored instance variables, often with a property (assign) associated, and conforming to a protocol. You need to manually set up the delegate behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a delegate on your custom view controller, as such:

```
@interface mergeConfig {
    id delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;        
@end

@implementation mergeConfig
@synthesize delegate;
@end
```

Then, elsewhere in the class for your view controller you can invoke whatever methods you need on your delegate.

Personally I like to improve the above by defining a protocol that my delegates comply to, as follows:

```
@protocol MyDelegateProtocol
- (void)delegateMethod;
@end

@interface mergeConfig {
    id<MyDelegateProtocol> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyDelegateProtocol> delegate;        
@end

@implementation mergeConfig
@synthesize delegate;
@end
```

Comment: How do I "invoke whatever methods you need on your delegate"? Just do delegate.methodName even though methodName doesn't exist in the same view controller?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. [delegate dismissView]; and as long as you have dismissView in the other file it'll work.

Comment: Thank you for the example code. I had no idea that "id<MyDelegateProtocol> delegate;" is the Objective-C way to declare a member variable of a type based on a protocol. Until I saw your code, I kept trying to do it the simpler Java way where we merely use the protocol (interface) name as we would use a class name: "MyDelegateProtocol delegate;".

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to dismiss the modal view controller, just call `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` at the appropriate time. No need for delegates unless you need to pass information back up the chain.